# Need simple progress bar for working VB ASP.NET file upload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, code-behind

OK, I've used this site many times for answers but this one has cost me a bit of time, so here goes.

I have a working ASP.NET multi-file upload where I set a hidden field var to later use for writing a folder to hold the images. This var is set in the vb code-behind from the querystring.

I'm using an asp:FileUpload below.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ji_key" runat="server" />
<asp:FileUpload CssClass="form-control"  type="file" runat="server" ID 
="oFile" NAME="oFile" multiple="true" />
<asp:button  class="btn-default" id="btnUpload" type="submit" text="Upload" 
runat="server">
```

The code behind (VB) creates the dir, writes each file to the dir, and by the end of the day will place these paths into a table in SQL Server.

The problem is I'm not familiar enough with the process to know what I'm looking for on the client end to draw a progress bar. Process is running fine and chrome shows progress. These are going to be large uploads from mobile devices so reasonably correct progress as to where we are in the upload will help.

A bootstrap modal would be cool, but anything bar-ish will work for now.

Thanks, js

Answer (score 0):

The link below describes a method using the UpdateProgress bar.

http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/05/show-progress-image-using.html